# How to decode rsa with public and private key

Tags: security, cryptography, rsa, decode, ctf

I have this public and private key, how to i  decode this ?

thank you, very much.

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCl0NyHA+z9w6LiYURla4UCcedc
2SpsS4SnVGdSSEHTMsc9NbMX2fVPX9q8yyYBMypvBYnVLc7gNozr3bziLLhOGWjv
Dh3zaC3/Q4wu6Osroo9Af9PoHr1riEve8ioz058mPP28TGOBb/oYa5TaeYw4GGMc
mqvZMrRlGhPZIOsePQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: and this is my flag: jmZpMnZtx0KZNkyYYo9poADkkETb7CkEgBsxoEyOrjwPW97OYpJnncZYNtIEhp0f+Blqf9dmc2EcDokA6k0haDmm1XsIiUVbfrx31C/1n5I3ZxzdclT0ZXIO441WGzIRlzoupnXPHiE9ZIOaUm06VTLzcBshFTl0rZhY4hjggik=

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209047/how-to-decode-rsa-with-public-and-private-key

Comment: Seriously, don't spend more time on your profile than on your questions.

Answer (score 0):

basically any ASN.1 decoder that recognizes DER structures will do...

for a free javascript version see https://lapo.it/asn1js/

Answer (score 0):

(This uses Python 3)

Open your CMD (windows) from start menu or TERMINAL (mac) from the utilities page in the launchpad. Type:

```
pip install pycrypto
```

if that gives you an error, try:

```
pip3 install pycrypto
```

(You might not have to do this) Select "Open Module" in the IDLE window, then type `crypto`. If it gives you an error, then you are good. Then, rename `crypto` to `Crypto` with a capital.

Go back to python and type this (in edit window):

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.importKey('file.pem') # where file.pem is where your keys are stored, in the format you had in your question
public = key.publickey()

output = public.encrypt('data'.encode('utf-8'),32) # 'data' is a placeholder
output = key.decrypt('data'.encode('utf-8'))
```

The output will be `bytes`, to convert to hexadecimal:

```py
print(output.hex())
```